# Center image within div

Tags: image, html, tags, center

I've looked around and tried the suggestions to center an image, and it usually works just fine, but I've got a situation where something isn't right.

If you go to the test page:
http://www.503rephotography.com/_temp/ - you will see the image is pushed to the right a little bit, and if you increase or decrease the size of your screen, you will see it may shift a little further away from the center position.

I'm new to CSS and may have something messed up that is making this not work; I used some tips on here to make the div with the content on the page be somewhat centered. Now I'm just trying to center an image within that div box. Any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: remove text-align: center from your div #hcontainer

Comment: What you have tried. Please show your code.

Comment: Sure, here's the code:

Comment: #vcontainer {
  position:absolute;
  display: table;
  height: 55%;
  width: 100%;
  border:none;
}
#hcontainer {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  z-index:2;
}
#content {
  color:#fff;
  width:75%;
  padding:30px;
  height:auto;
  display: inline-block;
  border: #000 1px solid;
  background: transparent url('images/55.png');
  text-align: left;
  z-index:2;
}

  .centeredImage
    {
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    padding:0px;
    }

Comment: <div id="topdiv">
 <img src="images/logo.png">  <font color="#fff">
</div>


  <div id="vcontainer"><div id="hcontainer">
    <div id="content">
    
     <p class="centeredImage"><img src="full/2.jpg"></p>
     <h1>Beautiful Real Estate Photography</h1>
     <h2>Serving the Portland metropolitan area</h2>


    </div>
  </div>

sorry for the messy code, may just be easier to view source...anyhow, I tried removing the text-align:center but the issue still persists. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a div container with `margin-left:auto:` and `margin-right:auto;` to center the content.

```
<div id="container">
            <div id="header">
                <h1 id="logo">
                    <a href="http://www.503rephotography.com">
                        <img src="images/logo.png" alt="503 rephotography">
                    </a>
                </h1>
                <ul class="navbar">
                    <li class="button"><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li>
                    <li class="button"><a href="p.html">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
                    <li class="button"><a href="#">CONTACT 503</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="topbar"></div>
            <div id="content">
                <img src="http://www.503rephotography.com/_temp/slides/1.jpg">
                <div class="sub">
                    <p>Content will go here....why can't I get this div box to be centered???</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Try this fiddle see if it's what you need: http://jsfiddle.net/ftPa3/